Delphi как передать переносы из Memo в Label?
Главная форма отображает текст из ini-файла. В него записаны настройки и текст из memo второй формы. Текст в оригинале был с кодом на переносы: Контора Рога и Копыта'+#13+'работает с 12:00 до 15:00 часов'+#13+'Личные приёмы с 13:00 до 14:00'
Вопрос, как это передать в Label?
В ini файле сохраняется построчно. В переменную тоже всё построчно принимается. Но на Label выводится лишь первая строка.

Дополнение. В статике всё отлично работает, когда в коде прописан текст label с '+#13'.
Но дело в том, что решил прикрутить Memo для редактирования текста.
Текст сохраняется в ini.
Т.е. при старте, FormCreate, В label идёт переменная прочитанная из ini. В самом ini есть переносы. Но не в Memo, ни в Label они уже не могут считаться из ini.
Как быть?
запись в ini F.WriteString('main_text', 'text', text1); переменная tex1 - string
Вид при вводе:

Вид из ini-файла:

результаты:



Также убедитесь что Label достаточно высок, или включен AutoSize.

@Kromster, В статике всё работает. Всё отлажено. Решил прикрутить редактирование текста с сохранением в ini.

MBo прав, попробуйте все же минимальный пример кода (и содержимого INI) в вопросе добавить.

При записи строки в ini используйте TBase64Encoding.Encode, а при чтении TBase64Encoding.Decode (см. System.NetEncoding.TBase64Encoding). Так вы избавитесь от проблем с переносом строк и наличия прочих спецсимволов, которые ломают формат ini.

Label умеет отображать многострочный текст:
label1.Caption := 'Контора Рога и Копыта'+#13+'работает с 12:00 до 15:00 часов'+#13+'Личные приёмы с 13:00 до 14:00';


но дело не в Label, а в работе с ini-файлами.
ini-файлы не предназначены для хранения многострочных параметров. При чтении ReadString использует функцию Windows GetPrivateProfileString, `которая находит строку вида
key=value

извлекает из неё value, и ничего не делает с далее идущими строками.
Вы можете при записи многострочного параметра заменять перенос строки на спецсимвол или последовательность, а при чтении выполнять обратную замену (StringReplace)
Возможно, стоит посмотреть в сторону других средств хранения и передачи - например, в JSON5 есть {multiline: (в стандартном JSON тоже приходится line1\\nline2 делать)

Доброго дня. Вы внимательно причитали суть вопроса? Я не первый год программирую.

Тогда попробуйте сделать так, чтобы вашу проблему можно было воспроизвести.

Дополнил вопрос пояснением.

"Я не первый год программирую" - в закладки ))

Если стандартными методами Delphi то лучше всего вот так.
implementation

{$R *.dfm}

    uses System.IniFiles;

    procedure TForm1.LoadBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
    begin
        if not OpenDialog1.Execute(Handle) then Exit;
        memo1.Lines.Clear;
        var inif := TIniFile.Create(OpenDialog1.FileName);
        try
            var Count := inif.ReadInteger('Memo1_Lines', 'Count', 0);
            for var I := 0 to Count do begin
                memo1.Lines.Add(inif.ReadString('Memo1_Lines', IntToHex(I, 4), ''));
            end;
        finally
            FreeAndNil(inif);
        end;

    end;

    procedure TForm1.SaveBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
    begin
        if not SaveDialog1.Execute(Handle) then Exit;
        var inif := TIniFile.Create(SaveDialog1.FileName);
        try
            var lines := Pred(Memo1.Lines.Count);
            inif.WriteInteger('Memo1_Lines', 'Count', lines);
            for var I := 0 to lines do begin
                inif.WriteString('Memo1_Lines', IntToHex(I, 4), Memo1.Lines[I]);
            end;
        finally
            FreeAndNil(inif);
        end;
    end;

end.

На выходе получится вот такой вот файлчик
[Memo1_Lines]
Count=4
0000=Memo1
0001=Is the
0002=perfect
0003=Container for Lines
0004==)

Если нестандартными то просто читаешь файл пока не встретишь нужную секцию, после читаешь до следующей секции.

Зачем такие сложности, если простой Base64 спасает от всех спецсимволов в сохраняемой строке?

Потому что стандартная читалка INI имеет жесткие ограничения на длину строки.

А, ну так не надо использовать ущербный TIniFile, пользуйтесь TMemIniFile без всяких там лимитов. Тем более, что на лимит в 2k символов вы можете напороться и в своём варианте. Никто же не гарантирует, что если есть перенос строк, то эти строки короткие.

Решение подсказано #MBo (и прочитано на старом delphibasics-ru).
//читаем из ini 
text1:=F.ReadString('main_text', 'text', 'сюда получаем текст из ini, содержащий это \\, это и будет наш символ переноса строки');

//далее делаем реплейсмент:
text2:= StringReplace(text1, '\\', #13, [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
Label1.Caption := text2;


Идея годная, но не забывайте про случаи, когда ваша изначальная строка, например, `\\111\``.
